# Does my wife need to update her married status in her passport before traveling with me as a tourist in the Schengen area?

Tags: schengen, passports, weddings

I am 28y.o, Tunisian, and work as a game programmer, I make €4000/month, And am getting married in March 2022.
For any touristic travel, I am going to be the "fund provider" for both me and my wife, I want to know if she **must** update her passport to her new married status before traveling *with me*, or is a marriage certificate enough ?
We are eventually gonna update our passport, but we're planning a 2 weeks honey moon in Japan/Korea (Visa-free for Tunisians, yay!) but I also want 2 weeks in Europe, specifically Barcelona (Spain) because we are going to relocate to it in the 2nd half of 2022, so I kinda want a "first taste" of it.

Thanks!

Comment: Your question is about possible passport difficulties in the future, in multiple countries who may well apply different immigration and transit rules. The question is therefore of broad and uncertain scope, and not well-suited to this site. Take the [Tour](https://travel.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn more. Look at it this way: if no country objects to the maiden-name passport and marriage certificate, you'll be OK. If, OTOH, If you run into a problem, you'll wish you'd updated her passport first. You can avoid the uncertainty and update her passport immediately upon your marriage.

Comment: You’ll need to apply for any visas and book your wife’s tickets in her maiden name if she continues to travel with her pre-marriage passport.

Comment: In general, she can travel with you without changing her passport _and also without bringing the marriage certificate._ Unmarried couples travel together all the time, and there is rarely a need for married couples to prove that they are married. Do you anticipate a particular reason for having to prove that you are married? A common reason is in connection with moving to a country to reside there for a long time, but this question explicitly doesn't concern your future relocation to Spain. In the end, the documents needed to show that you are married will depend on the reason for proving it.

Comment: @phoog My gf Tunisian job of ~$200/month won't allow her to get her own touristic Visa to the Schengen area, so i need to be the fund provided, and I asked about this ~2 years ago here: https://www.shorturl.at/mzPS4 and the answer is that we need to be married in order for me to provide the funding.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica am asking specifically about the Schengen area which if am not wrong they all share the same VISA rules, also the question is exclusively about the period where both me and my wife won't have the updated passport cause in our super-slow country it takes up to 6 weeks to update a passport.

Comment: That link isn't working for me.  I'm surprised that it isn't possible to support a traveling companion who is not your family member, but even under the assumption that this requirement does in fact exist, once she has the visa there should be no further need to prove that you are married (that is, during the travel itself).  For the visa application, a marriage certificate ought to be sufficient without changing the passport (unless the passport ceases to be valid under Tunisian law, which seems unlikely).

Comment: AFAIK most passports don't have marital status in them unless you explicitly want this. Furthermore, if you *need* proof of marriage, you'll have to present your marriage certificate anyway. Just book everything under her maiden name and take the marriage certificate and it should be fine

Comment: @phoog yeah i see your point, but the question is regarding the Visa application, but yeah it seems that a marriage certificate should be enough.

Comment: @JulianaKarasawaSouza make sense, thank you.

Comment: You say that the question is about the visa application, but the question title and body both say "before traveling."  If you want to focus on the visa application then perhaps it would be better to say "before applying for a visa."

Comment: @phoog my bad, for us traveling almost always mean a visa is required so i just thought it would be understood

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the comments from @phoog and @JulianaKarasawaSouza It seems that, if required, a marriage certificate would suffice and there is no need to have the passport up-to-date.